# REST Services - JSON deserialization error: Encountered unexpected character '<'

Tags: rest, json.net, deserialization, bing-maps

```
    public async void MakeRequest(string requestUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    throw new Exception(string.Format(
                    "Server error(HTTP {0}:{1}.",
                    response.StatusCode,
                    response.StatusDescription));
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
                object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
                root = (RootObject)objResponse;

                if (root == null)
                    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ThrowException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Link : http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes?wp.0=39.920829,32.853883&wp.1=39.877666,32.864728&key=BingMapsKey

Is there anything wrong in my in the codes above?

Answer (score 5):

Just change this line for make the query with JSON and not XML format

So from this ...

```
string query = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" +         
               queryString + "?output=xml" + " &key=" + BingMapsKey;
```

To this ...

```
string query = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" +
               queryString + "?output=json" + " &key=" + BingMapsKey;
```

i.e. just change `output=xml` to `output=json`

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me once I replace the undefined `RootObject` in your code with the `BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Response` type found in the [Bing Maps REST Service .NET Libraries](http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/bing-maps-rest-service-net-libraries/) that @rbrundritt suggested you use [in your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217651/metro-style-app-json-object-deserialization-error-rest-services)

Comment: hmm... I cut and pasted your code just as it and threw behind a button. I've put my VS2012 project on DropBox at https://www.dropbox.com/s/hoiszqnhwivuim2/jsondeser.zip - put in your Bing key and see what happens.  The app doesn't do anything, but you can put a break point on the return from ReadObject to see the data is there.